# draw multiline graph in core plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graph, charts, core-plot

I want to draw line bar and pi graph using core plot api. I don't know how to user code plot api.
Also this graphs having multiple line and bars for different units . I have attached image for that.

[image]

Like in this image there are three yAxis for different units. So how to make this in core plot. I also want to show the label on bottom of the graph as shown in image.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example apps provided with Core Plot to see what it can do. The Plot Gallery is a good place to start—it shows examples of every supported plot type.

To make a graph similar to the image in your question, you'll need these components:

1. If you want the three y-axes to have different scales, you'll need three different plot spaces. A new graph starts with one—simply add two more. You can use the same `xRange` for each plot space if you want the data points to line up vertically.
2. Look at the Axis Demo in the Plot Gallery to see how to add multiple axes. The example shows two y-axes; it's trivial to add a third. Assign each y-axis to a different plot space. Set the `gridLinesRange` on the axis that draws the grid lines to limit their length between the other axes.
3. The labels at the bottom can be created using a legend. Each plot has a `title` property that sets the text that appears in the legend. The icon next to the legend title (called a "swatch" in Core Plot) is drawn using the properties of the corresponding plot (line style, fill, plot symbol, etc.).